# Check if variable is string or array in Twig

Tags: twig

Is it possible to check if given variable is string in `Twig` ?

Expected solution:

`messages.en.yml`:

```
hello:
  stranger: Hello stranger !
  known: Hello %name% !
```

`Twig` template:

```
{% set title='hello.stranger' %}
{% set title=['hello.known',{'%name%' : 'hsz'}] %}

{% if title is string %}
  {{ title|trans }}
{% else %}
  {{ title[0]|trans(title[1]) }}
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible to do it this way ? Or maybe you have better solution ?

Comment: You can maybe do something with the `iterable` test? http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/iterable.html

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Can be done with the test `iterable`, added in twig1.7,  as Wouter J stated in the comment :

```
{# evaluates to true if the users variable is iterable #}
{% if users is iterable %}
    {% for user in users %}
        Hello {{ user }}!
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {# users is probably a string #}
    Hello {{ users }}!
{% endif %}
```

Reference : [iterable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tests/iterable.html)

Comment: Note: other objects can also be `iterable` even though they are not an `array`. Iterable is not a true test if something is an array. I have an answer how to make an array test like `{% if value is array %}` below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29642662/417822

Answer (score 15):

Ok, I did it with:

```
{% if title[0] is not defined %}
    {{ title|trans }}
{% else %}
    {{ title[0]|trans(title[1]) }}
{% endif %}
```

Ugly, but works.

Comment: dont even need the "is not defined" bit

Answer (score 15):

I found `iterable` to not be good enough since other objects can also be iterable, and are clearly different than an `array`.

Therefore adding a new `Twig_SimpleTest` to check if an item `is_array` is much more explicit. You can add this to your app configuration / after twig is bootstrapped.

```
$isArray= new Twig_SimpleTest('array', function ($value) {
    return is_array($value);
});
$twig->addTest($isArray);
```

Usage becomes very clean:

```
{% if value is array %}
    <!-- handle array -->
{% else %}
    <!-- handle non-array -->
{% endif % }
```

Comment: A sidenote here : This test will return false for every custom object implementing ArrayAcces, Traverseable, ...

Comment: Right, but the core issue is that not all `iterable` items are equal. The structure of an `iterable` can look different depending on type.

Comment: Where this class file should be put in Symfony2?

Comment: Not sure for Symfony2. You'll need to find a spot during your app boot or early on in a controller - but after twig has been loaded.

Comment: You put your test into a TwigExtension subclass (in the `getTests` method), register it as a service, and add the tag `twig.extension` to the service definition. The tag is what makes the TwigBundle take care of the `addExtension` for you. More details here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to check it correctly using code from the box.
It's better to create custom `TwigExtension` and add custom check (or use code  from `OptionResolver`).

So, as the result, for `Twig 3`, it will be smth like this

```
class CoreExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getTests(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigTest('instanceof', [$this, 'instanceof']),
        ];
    }

    public function instanceof($value, string $type): bool
    {
        return ('null' === $type && null === $value)
               || (\function_exists($func = 'is_'.$type) && $func($value))
               || $value instanceof $type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Assuming you know for a fact that a value is always either a string or an array:

```
{% if value is iterable and value is not string %}
    ...
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

This worked good enough for me in a project I was working on.  I realize you may need another solution.

Comment: Which version of `twig` are you using then? Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/8qwo34)