# Equivalent of is_array in Twig

Tags: twig

I'm working on a template and I need to check if something is an array. How do I do that in Twig?

I've tried

```
{% if my_var is iterable %}
  {% for v in my_var %}
      ...
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  {{ my_var }}
{% endif %}
```

but it always prints my_var, even when my_var is really an array, as evidenced when it prints out

```
Array
Array
myusername
../data/table.sqlite3
```

Comment: sorry 'bout my prev answer which I deleted... but you could engange in extending twig http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html, you might find a way to create your own filter there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if variable is string or array in Twig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876023/check-if-variable-is-string-or-array-in-twig)

Answer (score 4):

Another way :

```
{% if my_var.count()>1 %}
```

Comment: Impossible to invoke a method ("count") on a string variable ("").

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to create a custom filter use [`iterable`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/iterable.html), as per the docs :

> iterable checks if a variable is an array or a traversable object

```
{% if myVar is iterable %} ... {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add a custom filter:

```
$twig->addFilter('is_array', new \Twig_Filter_Function('is_array'));
```

Then use it like this:

```
{% if my_var|is_array %}
```

Comment: When using this method, you have to use it like this:
$twig->addFilter('is_array', new \Twig_Filter_Function('is_array'));

Or use {% is_array(my_var) %}