# Twig: how to check if a variable is a DateTime object

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I have to check if a variable is a `DateTime`object or a simple string to use it in my template.

If the variable is a `DateTime`, I have to format it as a date; simply print it if is a string.

```
{% if post.date is DateTime %}
    {% set postDate = post.date|date %}
{% else %}
    {% set postDate = post.date %}
{% endif %}

<p>Il {{ postDate }}
```

I think I should do this using a [Twig Test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id5) (as also suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29642662/1399706) StackOverflow Answer about `arrays`), but I don't well understand in which folder of my Symfony App I should put the code and how to register it in the application.

**Once wrote the test, how can I use it in my Twig templates in Symfony?**

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788138/instanceof-operator-in-twig-symfony-2

Comment: Or check if it quacks like a duck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482184/check-if-a-variable-is-a-date-with-twig

Comment: Thankyou! I've solved with a simple `{% if post.date.timezone is defined %}` found in one of the suggested links! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create a twig function

AcmeBundle\Twig\CheckExtension.php

```
<?php
namespace AcmeBundle\Twig;

class CheckExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            'isDateTime' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'isDateTime'),
        );
    }

    public function isDateTime($date) {
        return ($date instanceof \DateTime); /* edit */
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_check_extension';
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    acme_check_extension:
        class: AcmeBundle\Twig\CheckExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

in your template:

```
{% if isDateTime(post.date) %} 
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Twig test is more suitable for this needs

Comment: `return ($date instanceof \DateTime) ? true : false;` is redundant, `return ($date instanceof \DateTime);` should return the same result.